# Find a linear recurrence which gives every integer exactly once.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Find a linear recurrence which gives every integer exactly once.

$a_n$ = $a_{n-1} - 1$  or $a_n$ = $a_{n-1} + 1$
gives only the negative integers or poitive integers not both when we set $a_0= 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Such a sequence could look like this:

$$0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\dots$$

Try constructing the recurrence relation by using $(-1)^n$.

---

**Solution** (don't look until you've tried):

> $$a_{n+1}=a_n+(-1)^n(n+1) \quad \quad \text{with }\; a_0=0.$$

Comment: Another hint in this direction: Look at the successive differences between these terms!

Comment: Is the solution strictly a linear recurrence?

Comment: @coffeemath: Yes, it’s linear; it just isn’t homogeneous.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Done :)